# .htaccess redirect URL with id param to human friendly URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, rapache

I'm trying to create a URL redirect but so far everything I have tried just hasn't shown any effect on the site. I know ModRewrite is enabled as there are other rewrites taking place. The whole purpose of this is to handle old URLs from the former version of the website.

What I want to achieve is a redirect of a URL with the following format:
`/resources/view?id={id}` and redirect it to `/resources/{id}`.

I've been trying to do so with variants of this:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/view?id=([0-9+])$ /resources/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and also this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^/resources/view$ /resources/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /resources/view\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /resources/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^resources/(\d+)/?$ resources/view?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```